# combining two sets of custom field groups

Tags: custom-fields, fields

Ive have a site running for a while with two channels each with there own custom field group.

I now find that I need to be able to clone entries from each channel using mx cloner but because each channel has a different field group I cannot assign the new cloned entry to the other channel.

Each channel have 24 fields and approx 100 entries so I don't want to have to create a new shared field group and remake 200 odd entries.

I there a way to combine the two custom field groups into one group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.
You just need to change field groups association in table exp_channel_fields. Make you db backup then run next code (u can even use SQL Manager from CP)

```
UPDATE exp_channel_fields SET group_id = X WHERE group_id = Y
```

After that you just need to update field group for second channel. You can do this manually or run next query

```
UPDATE exp_channels SET field_group = X WHERE field_group = Y
```

And possible you will need to reset publish page layout.